# CAGradientLayer doesn't appear (Swift 3)

Tags: uiview, swift3, gradient

I'm making a weather app and for showing maximum and minimum temperature of the day, I'm using a UIView that's corners I've rounded by using .layer.cornerRadius. Now I want to add a gradient layer with different colors (symbolizing temperature), but the gradientLayer doesn't appear. Here's my viewDidLoad(), the views name is currentMinMaxTemperatureView:

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = currentMinMaxTemperatureView.bounds
    gradientLayer.cornerRadius = currentMinMaxTemperatureView.cornerRadius
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.blue, UIColor.yellow, UIColor.red]
    currentMinMaxTemperatureView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

Why doesn't it appear? When running this, my view looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

First, as @archLucifer mentioned, `CAGradientLayer` expects `CGColor`, not `UIColor`.

Simply convert your colours like so:

```
[UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
```

Second, you want to make sure you add your gradient **after** your `currentMinMaxTemperatureView` is added to the superview. Otherwise, its `bounds` will be `nil`.

Try adding the gradient later in your `UIViewController` lifecycle, like `ViewDidLayoutSubviews()`

Comment: Thanks for that tip regarding bounds!

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColour, UIColor.yellow.cgColour, UIColor.red.cgColour]
```